# Parse part of a path from a text file in windows command line

Tags: cmd

I have a text line containing the following line:
BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\Program Files\SomeSoftware\file.exe"

I want to parse and extract the text file for this text: C:\Program Files\
The problem is that the path can vary so it would have to parse beginning 1 charachter after the double quotes until one character after SomeSoftware.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%f in ('find "BINARY_PATH_NAME" ^< "a.txt"') do (
    echo Readed : "%%~g"
    echo Parent : "%%~dpg"
)
```

Use `find` to search for the line, and `for` command to parse filtered output. Line is splitted using colon and spaces as delimiters. First token (`BINARY_PATH_NAME`) is asigned to `%%f` and the rest of the line goes to `%%g`.

`%%~g` returns the readed value without quotes, and `%%~dpg` the drive and path of the file/folder referenced by `%%g`